# How to implement cancel method for a C++ library

Tags: c++

I'm developing a C++ library used for OCR purpose. The problem coming when I need to add the feature cancel/stop its work immediately (<= 0.4 seconds) after user send cancel signal (just a boolean function pointer), without any memory leaking error.
Now, I choose the solution to place a lot of checkpoint after each function that consume around 1% performance by profiling. Then I will throw an exception and catch that exception in the highest caller and use smart pointer to prevent my library from memory leaking too. It take 20 checkpoint to do that purpose because alot of them are inside a loop.
But I see that this solution is bad, because it can't ensure the target 0.4 seconds in most case. And the effort to prevent memory leak is very high too. Also, it's hard to maintain this logic when the library is continued to develope.

Can you propose for me an better solution to overcome this issue?
Thanks you very much!

My case is demo simply as bellow:

```cpp
#include "OCRSetting.h"
#include "OCRDocument.h"

bool is_cancel(false);

bool IsCancel() {
  return is_cancel;
}

int main() {
  // OCR setting
  OCRSetting setting;

  // Create document
  OCRDocument document(image_path, setting);
  document.SetCancelMethod(IsCancel);

  // This is a action take a lot of time, when this action happen, the controller
  // thread can change the result of IsCancel to true and the requirement is that
  // methid Export must return immedidately with response time smaller than 0.4 seconds
  // Target CPU frequency is 1.33 GHz
  int status = document.Export();

  return status;
}
```

Comment: You should build a proper multithreading program with gui, messages, events etc.

Comment: I already thought about multithreading solution. Maybe I can create 2 threads, one thread is used to check the cancel signal with 0.4s period, the other thread is used to do main work. But I don't know how to send the cancel signal detected in checking thread to the main thead and how main thread can stop without memory leak?

Comment: It's not done that way. You use synchronization priminitives (events, mutex, etc) for "waiting" on a command.

Comment: The probably cheapest communication is an atomic e.g. [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). One thread may set the atomic to signal cancel. The OCR thread has to check this in a loop periodically (and to bail out or not depending on that test).

Comment: Can you demo your idea by code ? I still do not catch your ideas yet :(

Comment: Sending a signal is easy. You could pass a future into the function which is launched by the thread, and from the main thread you can then send the signal (call set_value on a promise for instance). But, your worker thread will have to check the status of that future, just like in your example. You can't guarantee the 0.4s, and forcing a kill is not an option (imagine your thread locks some resources and you kill it...).